# Sheldon Axler Measure Integration Real Analysis Section 2E Exercise 14

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

As you can tell from the title, this is an exercise from Axler's measure theory book, and I am struggling with the following problem:

Suppose $b_1,b_2,\dots$ is a sequence of real numbers. Define $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^k|x-b_k|} & \text{ if } x \notin \{b_1,b_2,\dots\},\\
 \infty & \text{ if } x \in \{b_1,b_2,\dots\}
\end{array}\right.$$
Prove that $|\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) < 1\}| = \infty$.

I am not sure what to do. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sets
$$
E_k = \{x : |x-b_k| > 2^{-k}\},\qquad k=1,2,3\dots,\\
E = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k .
$$
If $x \in E_k$ then
$$
|x-b_k| > 2^{-k} ,\\
4^k|x-b_k| > 2^{k} ,\\
\frac{1}{4^k|x-b_k|} < 2^{-k} .
$$
If $x \in E$ then
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^k|x-b_k|} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} = 1 .
$$
What is the measure of $E$?  To compute that, consider complements:
$$
E_k^c = \{|x-b_k| \le 2^{-k}\},\qquad |E_k^c| = 2\cdot 2^{-k} ,\\
|E^c| = \left|\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k^c\right| \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty |E_k^c|
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2\cdot 2^{-k} < \infty ,
$$
and therefore $|E| = \infty$.